# How to get value of FormData that is passed from Angular in Laravel 4?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, coffeescript, laravel-4

I'm uploading image (and other data at the same time) using angular and passed to Laravel's route using Angular service, all using the `FormData` function in javascript. Here's my code for uploading (in coffeescript):

```
            tag = null
            if $('span.tag').length > 0
                tag = $('span.tag').map(->
                    $.trim @innerHTML
                ).get().join(",")

            fd = new FormData()
            fd.append "title", $scope.title
            fd.append "subtitle", $scope.subtitle
            fd.append "date", $scope.date
            fd.append "time", $scope.time
            fd.append "category", $scope.category
            fd.append "content", $scope.content
            fd.append "tag", $scope.tag
            fd.append "caption", $scope.caption
            fd.append "active", !$scope.active

            if $scope.file
                fd.append "image", $scope.file

            alert fd

            UploadService.news.save fd
            , ( (response) ->
                alert response.data
            )
```

And my `UploadService` is just this, pointing to Laravel's route:

```
app.factory "UploadService", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
    news: $resource("upload/news")
    member: $resource("404/upload/member")
]
```

My problem is that I can't read the data passed from the `FormData` onto Laravel, even this :

```
return Response::json(['data' => $_POST['title']]);
```

or

```
return Response::json(['data' => Input::get['title']]);
```

will return `undefined index 'title'`, which part of my code is wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried dumping all input data via:

    dd(Input::all());

I noticed you used 

    Input::get['title']

in your question, which wouldn't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is a test I just did to check if FormData works:

```
Route::post('test', function() {

    Log::info(Input::all());

    return Response::json(['data' => Input::all()]);

});
```

Then tail the log:

```
php artisan tail
```

And you should get something like:

```
[2014-04-04 20:10:19] server.INFO: {"_token":"MIFCleetMa029UGpUcvXUhawmVdJyl65zYBmXDHM","id":"1""first_name":"Antonio Carlos","last_name":"Ribeiro"}
```

This is my (vanilla) Javascript code, should work as is in an Angular app too.

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
var formData = new FormData(form);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'http://development.consultoriodigital.net/test', true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

xhr.send(formData);
```

You also must get the form back in your console.

The `form1` form may contain any number of form inputs, doesn't matter.

A note about this line:

```
return Response::json(['data' => Input::get['title']]);
```

It should be

```
return Response::json(['data' => Input::get('title')]);
```